# Why does superset load_examples says "admin user does not exist" even thought one exists?

Tags: apache-superset

Following [official instructions](https://apache-superset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) I got this:

`Admin user does not exist.`

Even though I ran `superset fab create-admin` and everything was ok.

Answer (score 10):

I found the reason is `load_examples` requires the exact name `admin` as the username for the administrator. I changed it to `admin1` and it was not recognized.

This should be mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Good point. We ask for the admin username, but in most of the codebase we simply assume it's "admin". Would you mind filing an issue on Github for this? Thanks!

Comment: I also had this error message after updating from 0.38 to 1.0.1 and when displaying world map charts.

Comment: I logged this issue: https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/13106

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by removing the db and then re-initializing it, as follows:

Delete db:

```
cd /home/<user>/.superset/
rm -f superset.db
```

Reinitialize database:

```
superset db upgrade
```

[Repeat the procedure according with the doc](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-scratch):

```
export FLASK_APP=superset
superset fab create-admin
```

And it should work properly:

```
Username [admin]: admin
User first name [admin]: 
User last name [user]: 
Email [admin@fab.org]: 
Password: 
Repeat for confirmation: 
Recognized Database Authentications.
Admin User admin created.
```